# Javascript combining AND && or || conditions in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

i’m creating a switch statement with javascript. I want to use the `&&(AND)` and `||(OR)` conditions. I want `var user = prompt` to accept the inputs `14` or `13`, or `14km` or `13km`, or `14 km` or `13 km` (with spaces) from user. I want to do the same for all the other cases.

How do I do this?

```
var user = prompt("How fast can you run per hour in kilometers (km)?").toUpperCase();

switch(user) {

case '14km':
    if ( 14 || 13 == true) {
    console.log("Woah!, your almost as fast as Usain Bolt!");
                           }
    else {
        console.log("RUN FASTER");
         }
    break;
case '12km':
    if ( 12 || 11 == true) {
    console.log("Your quick, but not as quick as me!");
                           }
    else {
        console.log("TOO SLOW");
         }
    break;
case '10km':
    if ( 10 && 9 )    {
    console.log("Average!");
             }
    break;
case '8km':
    console.log("OK tortoise!");
    break;
case '6km':
    console.log("I think it's better you get some rest");
    break;
default:
    console.log("I didn't understand you? Can you repeat that please");
}
```

Comment: Whats the logic in the if block `if ( 14 || 13 == true)` and whats with _(with spaces)_

Comment: i'm learning on code academy and it says I have to use && and || operators. my reasoning with spaces was to accept user input in the prompt as 12km or 12 km.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combile conditions for switch `case` statements with `&&` or `||`, but you can specify several `case` statements for the same code, like this:

```
switch(user) {
    case '14km':
    case '13km':
    case '14':
    case '13':
        console.log("Woah!, your almost as fast as Usain Bolt!");
        break;
    case '12km':
    case '11km':
    case '12':
    case '11':
        console.log("Your quick, but not as quick as me!");
        break;
    case '10km':
    case '9km':
    case '10':
    case '9':
        console.log("Average!");
        break;
    case '8km':
    case '8':
        console.log("OK tortoise!");
        break;
    case '6km':
    case '6':
        console.log("I think it's better you get some rest");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("I didn't understand you? Can you repeat that please");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a little trick with the switch statement code flow.

See this fiddle for an example to your question
https://jsfiddle.net/p51h5y4f/1/

See:

```
case 14:
case 13:
    console.log("Woah!, your almost as fast as Usain Bolt!");
    break;
case 12:
case 11:
    console.log("Your quick, but not as quick as me!");
    break;
```

In there, the user enters in an int to the box prompt, if it's 14 or 13, it goes into the first response, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use operator with `switch`. However you can evaluate multiple case in single block.

```
//Using regular expression extract on number
//So that you don't need to evaluate (14 km/14 KM/14km/14KM/14)
user = user.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');

//Convert to number
user = parseInt(user , 10);

switch(user) {
    case 14:
    case 13:
        console.log("Woah!, your almost as fast as Usain Bolt!");
        break;
    case 12:
    case 11:
        console.log("Your quick, but not as quick as me!");
        break;
    case 10:
    case 9:
        console.log("Average!");
        break;
    case 8:
        console.log("OK tortoise!");
        break;
    case 6:
        console.log("I think it's better you get some rest");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("I didn't understand you? Can you repeat that please");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

> want var user = prompt to accept the inputs 14 or 13, or 14km or 13km,
>   or 14 km or 13 km (with spaces) from user

The user must input values within a html form . Then you get the values

```
document.getElementById('KM').value
```

Comment: Could you please explain why my solution is so bad at least i can learn.